# How to input multiple files with MRJob

Tags: python, file, hadoop, input, mrjob

I am leraning hadoop and wanna use two diferent files in my script, but i don`t know the commado in terminal that do this. To read one file I use:

`python script.py hdfs://dataset/u.data -r hadoop`

I want to read the file u.item too, which is in the same diretory, dataset.

i try `python script.py hdfs:///dataset/u.data hdfs:///dataset/u.item -r hadoop`, but it didn`t work